# VBA connection string to Azure database

Tags: vba, azure

I'm trying to query data from an Azure database into an excel worksheet.  I'm getting the error "multiple-step OLE DB operation generate errors.  Check each OLE DB status value, if available.  No work was done."

My connection string:

```
conn.Open "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source= **server name**.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=**db name**;Integrated Security=Active Directory Integrated;"
```

I have searched the site and found some useful examples, but I cannot get any of them to work.  Would greatly appreciate any help.

Jim

Comment: what excel version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 365 for excel

Comment: This would be much easier and faster if you use [PowerQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-what-is-power-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, your connection string seems ok.

```
conn.Open "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source= "& yourServer &".database.windows.net;Initial Catalog= "& yourDatabase &";Integrated Security=Active Directory Integrated;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the below string.

Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source= servername.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=db name;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;Use Encryption for Data=true;